# How to call method from running windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, .net-2.0

I have created and started windows service Service1 (with exe as MyService.exe) using c# 2005. .
I have included a method GetMyRandomNumber() that returns a random double value.

The problem here is how could use this running service and how could i call the method.

I have tried adding reference of MyService.exe and access the method as -

```
Service1 s = new Service1();
MessageBox.Show(s.GetMyRandomNumber().ToString());
```

But found that the method is not called from the running instance of the service i.e. even though i stop the service the statements are executed.

Could someone explain me how can I call the method from running instance of the service.

Thanks for sharing your valuable time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should have a look at Remoting

- Remoting in C# (Link no Longer available)
- [How To Host .NET Remoting Objects in
  Windows Service Application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/winservicehost.aspx)
- How to Use .Net Remoting Using (Link no Longer available)
- [A Simple Introduction to .NET
  Remoting](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4699/a-simple-introduction-to-net-remoting/)

Comment: Remoting is not a good choice if on .NET 3.0+. I prefer Alan's answer.

Answer (score 16):

In your code, you aren't actually calling the service, instead you are referencing the executable and invoking a method from that assembly (at run time the .NET Framework will use a local assembly to execute the code, not your running service).

To do what you want, you have a number of options.

In .NET 2.0, you would make use of .NET Remoting. You create a remoting interface, which other assemblies can use to invoke methods across executables.

In .NET 3.0, remoting was replaced by WCF. Your service would become a WCF service, which would expose the GetRandomNumber() as part of its data contract. Applications can consume the contract and connect to your service to call the method.

There are a number of good tutorials on the web for both .NET Remoting or its replacement, Windows Communication Foundation.

Comment: +1 WCF would be the correct choice in this scenario if on .NET 3.0+. For completeness sake I'd like to add that although WCF replaces Remoting in almost all cases, it still has a niche for cross-AppDomain communication - I wouldn't use WCF for communicating across AppDomain boundaries, but in all other cases, WCF is the correct choice.

Answer (score 4):

WCF will be an overkill for communication on the same computer. [Pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.aspx) is a simpler and more effective solution.

Comment: He is using C# 2005 (.Net 2.0 ?) so WCF is not an option.

Comment: Good observation.  I hadn't noticed that.

Comment: I am looking alternative for WCF, your answer got my vote

Answer (score 2):

Communicating with a running service is no different from invoking methods on any other running process. That means that you will need to dig out your standard tools for process-to-process communication.

[Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx) (WCF) would be my default choice. You can host a WCF service in your Windows Service and expose it through a Named Pipe endpoint for efficient communication.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx) and IPC ([inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)) to communicate with your service and execute your method.