# Execute program on separate thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, reflection, console, invalidoperationexception

I'm trying to interact with a third party application but whenever I try and call a method, I get an error message saying `System.InvalidOperationException: Operation must be performed on the application thread`. The exception is of type `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException` and I'm guessing this is because my app is running in a completely separate process. Is there a way to get my program, which is a console application, to start running on the same thread as the third party app?

Comment: You probably want to clarify your question a bit. Third-party *control* and third-party *application* are two different beasts. It would also help to mention *which* third-party.

Comment: Yes, apologies, I don't know why I put control. I meant third party application. I can't really say which application due to company policy but any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Buy whomever wrote that code a cigar, he's letting you know that his code doesn't support threads.  Most code doesn't check and just fails randomly.  It's a guess what "application thread" might mean, do make sure to contact the vendor for support, but it most likely means the main thread.  The one that creates the user interface and pumps a message loop.  A common requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I guess I'll have to get in touch with the vendor tomorrow. I'm just glad I'm not missing anything obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get two separate applications to run in a single thread.

If you are trying to interact with some UI controls in your application, you can use `.Invoke()` to make sure the relevant code is executed in the UI thread.

If you're trying to manipulate the a third party *application*, the appropriate solution depends entirely on how you're interacting with it. Does it provide an API? Sending messages to its window handle? ??

In order to interact with a running instance of another application, you'll need to use something like remoting (obsolete) or WCF. Essentially, the other application acts as a server, and you have to somehow connect to it. Referencing its assembly, instantiating one of the classes therein defined and calling methods on that instance won't let you talk to an already-executing process.

Comment: Thank you. I can't say too much due to company policy (I know that won't help much), but I meant third party application. I'm trying to leverage public methods it already exposes within its assembly. When I try and call any of the methods from my assembly, that error gets thrown.

Comment: If you're loading their assembly and calling methods that way, then you're already calling it from within your application's thread, so you shouldn't be getting those exceptions. If you're connecting to a running instance of the application, there should be a WCF or other interface available. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979016/how-to-call-method-from-running-windows-service

Comment: I've never used WCF as I assumed it was only useful if the I had full control over the third party application and my console application. I'll look into using WCF to invoke third party methods.Thank You.

Comment: @SSL As I said in my edits above, WCF only makes sense if the application in question supports it. If I were in your shoes, I'd contact the vendor and ask them what the recommended approach is.

Comment: I'll have to find out about WCF support, but if it doesn't , is there no other way of interacting with the public methods of the assembly (of a running instance)?

Comment: A running app has to act as a server in this case. Like any kind of server (web, database, etc), it needs to provide a way for you to talk to it. There are a lot of hacks for talking to an app that doesn't intend to be used this way, but they're flakey at best, and definitely not suitable for a production app.

Comment: I was worried that might be the case, so I'll see if the vendor can provide some other robust way of interacting with it. From what I gather, they plan to release a public API 'in the future' which is why most of the common methods are already public but I guess it's a bit hit and miss to work with it at the moment.

Comment: If they've exposed classes from one of their assemblies, then I'd guess that they expect you to use that, but (not to belabor the point) anything you do that way, barring some bizarre magic on their part, will be with instances created in your application's process, not with an already-running process. If they literally use the term "API," that's probably want they want you to do.

Comment: Yup, they said the same thing. If I create my own instance it will work, but there's no way to work with an existing instance that wasn't launched from my own process. Thanks for the help!