# WCF: How can I reach an instance of a service from inside an instance of a service library?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a long-running WCF service hosted in a Windows service.  I have a service library whose purpose is to report on the state of the service.  How can I get to the instance of the service from inside an instance of the service library?

To illustrate, I created a service that records the time it started, and exposes a method to report how long it's been running.  The service library needs to be able to call the service's ElapsedSeconds() method, so the the library needs a reference to the running service.

I thought I could use OperationContext.Current.  Here's my service library class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TimerService
{
public class TimerServiceLib : ITimerServiceLib
{
    TheTimerService m_timerService;

    public TimerServiceLib()
    {
        var currentContext = OperationContext.Current;
        var instanceContext = currentContext.InstanceContext;
        m_timerService = (TheTimerService)instanceContext.GetServiceInstance();
    }

    public double SecondsSinceStart()
    {
        return m_timerService.ElapsedSeconds();
    }
}
}
```

But the call to GetServiceInstance() creates a new instance of TimerServiceLib(), which of course gives me an infinite loop.  So, what is the correct way to do this?

Here is my service class, actually being hosted in a console application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TimerService
{
public partial class TheTimerService : ServiceBase
{
    private DateTime m_startTime;
    ServiceHost m_svcHost;

    public TheTimerService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Init();
        m_startTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public double ElapsedSeconds()
    {
        return (DateTime.Now - m_startTime).TotalSeconds;
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        if (m_svcHost != null)
        {
            m_svcHost.Close();
        }

        string httpAddress = "http://localhost:1234/TimerService";
        string tcpAddress = "net.tcp://localhost:1235/TimerService";

        Uri[] adrbase = { new Uri(httpAddress), new Uri(tcpAddress) };
        m_svcHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(TimerServiceLib), adrbase);

        ServiceMetadataBehavior mBehave = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        m_svcHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(mBehave);

        var debugBehavior = m_svcHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
        debugBehavior.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;

        BasicHttpBinding httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        m_svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITimerServiceLib), httpBinding, httpAddress);
        m_svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange),
                                     MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");
        NetTcpBinding tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
        m_svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITimerServiceLib), tcpBinding, tcpAddress);
        m_svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange),
                                     MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding(), "mex");

        m_svcHost.Open();

        // SimShopServiceLib.m_shop = new CSimShopManager();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call method from running windows service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979016/how-to-call-method-from-running-windows-service)

Comment: Probably you should move the timing code into the Windows Service class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

First, modify your TimerServiceLib and do the constructor injection of **TheTimerService**:

```
public class TimerServiceLib : ITimerServiceLib
{
    private readonly TheTimerService m_timerService;

    public TimerServiceLib(TheTimerService theTimerService)
    {
         m_timerService = theTimerService;
    }

    public double SecondsSinceStart()
    {
        return m_timerService.ElapsedSeconds();
    }
}
```

Then, in your **Init()** upon creation of ServiceHost, instantiate first your service and pass the TheTimerService. Since your are creating the ServiceHost inside your windows service, wich is **TheTimerService** you can pass **this**.

```
Uri[] adrbase = { new Uri(httpAddress), new Uri(tcpAddress) };
var timerServiceLib = new TimerServiceLib(this)
m_svcHost = new ServiceHost(timerServiceLib , adrbase);
```

For more details about passing object in you service see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585487.aspx).

**Disclaimer** : The above code is not tested.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.  I don't think I followed this exactly, but the link gave me the answer.  I marked my TimerServiceLib class to be singleton ([ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]).  Then, inside TheTimerService.Init(), I made this change:

            TimerServiceLib theServiceLib = new TimerServiceLib();

            // m_svcHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(TimerServiceLib), adrbase);

            m_svcHost = new ServiceHost(theServiceLib, adrbase);

Comment: I'm not comfortable with StackOverflow commenting rules, such as not being able to edit a comment after five minutes.  Here's how I wanted to rewrite the above comment:

I put the starting time inside the TimerServiceLib class, and marked that singleton.  In TheTimerService.Init(), I instantiated a TimerServiceLib object so the starting time would be set.  

I think that's opposite of what you suggested.  Your suggestion would let me keep the important logic in TheTimeService, which is where it belongs.  I will try it that way.