# Use Windows Service from a Windows form application

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a windows service that has a function, lets say

```
Sum(int a,int b)
```

How can I use this function from my windows form application?

Comment: I have created the service and application... but no idea how to communicate between them..

Comment: Googled for "C# call method in windows service": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979016/how-to-call-method-from-running-windows-service

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call method from running windows service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979016/how-to-call-method-from-running-windows-service)

Answer (score 3):

Do not use .NET Remoting.  That technology is out-of-date.

If you are wanting to invoke the `Sum()` method in the Windows service from the client-side application, Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) would be a logical choice.  You can view my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775124/creating-a-user-interface-for-monitoring-and-interacting-with-a-running-windows/1777650#1777650) for an example of how this might be done.